# How can I load a SVG directly instead of importing via a js file for use in a leaflet divIcon?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg, vuejs2, leaflet

I have a Vue 2 sample project at https://github.com/ericg-vue-questions/leaflet-test

I need to use this SVG inside of a leaflet [divIcon](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#divicon).

```
      const cloudIcon = L.divIcon({
        html: thecloud, // this.cloudSvg, // thecloud,
        className: 'my-custom-icons',
        iconSize: [size, size],
        iconAnchor: [size/2, size/2]
      })
```

Additionally, I may need to make some modifications to the SVG, so I need the actual SVG source.

What does work is placing the SVG source inside of a [javascript file](https://github.com/ericg-vue-questions/leaflet-test/blob/main/src/components/TheCloud.js) and importing it by doing:

```
import {thecloud} from './TheCloud';
```

and I see:

[image: working image]

I did try:

```
  data() {
    return{
      cloudSvg: require('./TheCloud.svg')
    }
  },
```

But that did not work and I see:

[image: not working]

Is there a way to do this? I would like to avoid the extra step of placing the SVG source inside of javascript files. It seems like this should be unnecessary.

Comment: Can you use `iconUrl`? -- `The URL to the icon image (absolute or relative to your script path).`

Comment: Out of curiosity, I tried `iconUrl: './TheCloud.svg',`, but that did not work. Additionally, I may need to make some modifications to the SVG, so I need the actual SVG source.

Comment: I don't know much about `vuejs`, but in HTML, `<img src="./TheCloud.svg"/>` should work.

Comment: I need the src of the svg itself as I may need to make modifications to it.

Comment: SVG has no difference from other asset like PNG. I think `require('./TheCloud.svg')` should work.

Comment: As mentioned, the require does not work.

Comment: I think what I am missing is somehow using a loader to get require (or even import) to work as I need it to. However, how to configure my project to do so is something I still need to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preferred solution is to use what I am calling the fetch-method.

The changes I made was to:

1. move `TheCloud.svg` to the `public/` folder.
2. use the `fetch` to obtain the svg source

```
const response = await fetch( "/TheCloud.svg");
const source = await response.text();
```

While embedding SVGs in the source code works well when there is just a single or a small number of SVGs, when the number of SVGs becomes large, I believe this method is among the best solutions.

I have updated the repo with the fetch-method implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I found one method that is working, but I am sure there are ways to improve it.

The following changes are on the [raw-loader](https://github.com/ericg-vue-questions/leaflet-test/tree/raw-loader) branch.

1. `yarn add raw-loader`
2. create a `vue.config.js` file at the root of the project with the following contents to configure the `raw-loader`.

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('raw-loader')
      .test(/\.txt$/i)
      .use('raw-loader')
        .loader('raw-loader')
        .end()
  }
}
```

3. Changed my `data()` method to:

```
  data() {
    return{
      center: [37.781814, -122.404740],
      cloudSvg: require('./TheCloud.svg'),
      cloudSrc: require('./TheCloud.txt')
    }
  },
```

adding `cloudSrc: require('./TheCloud.txt')`.

`TheCloud.txt` is a duplicate of `TheCloud.svg`, but with a different extension so the `raw-loader` will process it.

4. Change the usage of `divIcon` to:

```
      const cloudIcon = L.divIcon({
        html: this.cloudSrc.default, // thecloud, // this.cloudSvg, // thecloud,
        className: 'my-custom-icons',
        iconSize: [size, size],
        iconAnchor: [size/2, size/2]
      })
```

I cannot say I understand everything going on here, like why I need the `.default` part or the webpack configuration section, but this is working.